# Which indexes in which situations are more efficacy in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I use SQL Server 2012. I want know in what situation I have to use `CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX ....` and in what situation I have to use `Create NonClustered Index... Include` and in what situations I have to use `Create NonClustered Index...` with all columns.

What are the advantage and disadvantage relative to the other?

Example :

```
Use [AdventureWorksDW2012]
Go

CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX csi_FactResellerSales
ON dbo.FactResellerSales
(ProductKey, UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, OrderDate);

SELECT ProductKey, UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, OrderDate
FROM dbo.FactResellerSales;
```

[image]

```
Drop Index csi_FactResellerSales On [dbo].[FactResellerSales] 
Create NonClustered Index Ardalan
    On [dbo].[FactResellerSales] (ProductKey) include(UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, 
                                                      OrderDate)

SELECT ProductKey, UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, OrderDate
FROM dbo.FactResellerSales;
```

[image]

```
Drop Index Ardalan On [dbo].[FactResellerSales]
Create NonClustered Index Ardalan1
    On [dbo].[FactResellerSales] (ProductKey,UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, OrderDate)

SELECT ProductKey, UnitPrice, CustomerPONumber, OrderDate
FROM dbo.FactResellerSales;
Drop Index Ardalan1 On [dbo].[FactResellerSales]
```

[image]

I thing `NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX` has less I/O than the anothers.

Comment: Your queries have no `where` clauses, so any of the indexes with all four keys are covering indexes for the query.  The ones that "include" columns are marginally more efficient because the "included" column values are not in the index hierarchical table structure.

Comment: if I used a where on column's UnitPrice,what would your answer?

Comment: Then it should be the first column in the index.

Comment: yes. but witch of index is better?

Comment: *and in what situations I have to use ... with all columns* - that's usually pretty pointless - an index with all columns pretty much **never** makes any sense, really! You're just duplicating the whole table and gaining nothing!

Comment: ok. but in this situation which type is better?

Comment: There's no way to say "always do X" when it comes to indexing - it comes down to *your* tables, *your* data, *your* queries (all of them) and what trade-offs are acceptable to *you*. You need to *measure* your performance realistically and then determine whether it's worth investing any time to improve on that performance, and if it is, the easiest thing to do is to *try* each index you are considering and *measure* the performance differences.